# error when use go get -d github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying install tensorflow , i follow guide and install first library for linux,

when i use `go get -d github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go` , y received this error :

```
cannot find package "github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go/core/protobuf/for_core_protos_go_proto" in any of:    
/usr/lib/go/src/github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go/core/protobuf/for_core_protos_go_proto (from $GOROOT)       
/home/respirar/go/src/github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go/core/protobuf/for_core_protos_go_proto (from $GOPATH)
```

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

According to this blog: https://syslog.ravelin.com/go-tensorflow-74d1101fab3f, "As of June 2021 Go is no longer supported by Tensorflow". I suggest using "https://github.com/galeone/tfgo" instead.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)